# How to obtain Task instance from Service handler method in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, service, task

I have a JavaFX service in which Task is created to do some work:

```
public class MyService extends Service<Void> {
    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                // do some work
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I also have a handler for success:

```
myService.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle( final WorkerStateEvent event ) {
        // check what Task has finished
    }
});
```

As it is possible to run the service more than once concurrently, I wan't to be able to distinguish from success handler what instance of Task has finished. Looking into the doc, I could not find any way, how to do it.

My idea was to extend Task to contain some id, e.g. integer, and then to be able obtain that instance from event handler.

Any idea, how to achieve such behavior would be much welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that each instance of a service may have at most 1 Task active at each time. (From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html): *"A Service creates and manages **a** Task..."*.) That task may of course spawn additional threads, but then it is itself responsible for synchronizing them. You can also have multiple instances of a single service class, which is probably what you want. The state of each service instance is bound to the state of its corresponding Task, but, unlike Tasks, a service can be restarted (then a new Task is created).

Comment: "As it is possible to run the service more than once concurrently". This is not correct. A given service instance can only execute one task at a time.

Comment: IMHO, `Service` can run multiple `Tasks`, just `Service` event handlers will get invoked based on a state of the `Task`.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would question why you needed to do this. The task itself should encapsulate all the logic that is specific to its own particular instance. It feels like there should be a better solution to whatever it is you're trying to achieve.

So the most obvious way to do this would be to have your `Task` return the value you are interested in. E.g.

```
public class MyService extends Service<Integer> {

    private int nextId = 0 ;

    @Override
    protected Task<Integer> createTask() {
        private final int id = ++nextId ;
        return new Task<Integer>() {
            @Override
            protected Integer call() throws Exception {
                // do some work
                return id;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then

```
Service<Integer> service = new MyService();
service.setOnSucceeded(e -> System.out.println("Task " + service.getValue() + " finished"));
```

Note also that you can override the `succeeded()` method of `Task` (as well as registering a handler with the service). So you can do

```
public class MyService extends Service<Void> {

    private int nextId = 0;

    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {

            final int id = ++nextId ;

            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                // do some work
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void succeeded() {
                super.succeeded();
                System.out.println("Task "+id+" completed successfully");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The `succeeded()` method is invoked on the FX Application Thread.

If you really want to manage this via the service, you could just keep a reference to the latest task that was started in the service implementation. Since a `Service` can only run one task at a time, when the service enters the `SUCCEEDED` state, this is guaranteed to be the task that just completed. For example:

```
public class MyService extends Service<Void> {

    private Task<Void> mostRecentTask ;

    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                // do some work
                return null;
            }
        };
        task.setOnRunning(e -> mostRecentTask = task);
        return task ;
    }

    public Task<Void> getMostRecentTask() {
        return mostRecentTask ;
    }
}
```

Then

```
MyService service = new MyService();
service.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
    Task<Void> completedTask = service.getMostRecentTask();
    // ...
});
```

But, as I said before, it feels like there should be a more elegant way to achieve whatever it is you're trying to do at a more fundamental level.

Comment: Many thanks James_D for detailed answer and explanation. I thought there can be more Tasks at the same time. I mean that Service.restart() calls cancel() on current Task (but cancelled state may be ignored in call() method or it can take time to stop currently running Task), but then it creates and runs a new one. But if it is really ensured that there can be only one  running Task at given time, then my answer does not make sense.

Comment: As I understand it, if you call `cancel()`, the current task (if there is one) enters the `CANCELLED` state (whether or not its `call()` method actually exits). From there, it can never enter the `SUCCEEDED` state, so the `onSucceeded` handler can never be invoked for that task.

Comment: Just wrote some test code for that, and it is indeed what happens.

Comment: You are correct James_D, `Service.onSucceeded()` handler will never get invoked even if `Task.call()` method was successfully finished, but the state of the `Task` is in `CANCELLED` state. Please correct the following if I am wrong: In fact, 'Task.call()' method can be run concurrently if there are multiple `Task` instances for a given `Service`. It means it's programmer's responsibility to implement `call()` method correctly so that it checks whether the `Task` is not in `CANCELLED` state; and if it is, it's programmer's responsibility to terminate the method.

Comment: That sounds correct. `reset()` or `restart()` will put the current task in the `CANCELLED` state (and interrupt it if it is blocking), but the `call` method may continue to execute if it is not written to check for cancelation (or interruption).